# How to sort a file by a column which is a mix of numeric, alphabet and punctuation characters?

Tags: sort

I have a text file which is of the form -

```
b   SN:2
d   SN:5
f   SN:10
g   SN:11
h   SN:15
i   SA:3
j   SN:1
k   SN:4
```

And I want to sort by the second column, actually the numerical value in the second column.  I've tried -

```
$ sort -n -k2,2 file
$ sort -k2.4,2.5n file
```

but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you don't use `-t` option (or `-b` with [GNU sort](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort)), so you must count from beginning of leading spaces. POSIX defined [sort -k EXTENDED DESCRIPTION](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html#tag_20_119_13) as:

```
A field comprises a maximal sequence of non-separating characters and, in 
the absence of option -t, any preceding field separator
```

So you must use:

```
$ sort -nk2.7 file
j   SN:1
b   SN:2
i   SA:3
k   SN:4
d   SN:5
f   SN:10
g   SN:11
h   SN:15
```

But you can use `:` as field separator, then sort numeric by second field:

```
$ sort -t':' -nk2 file
j   SN:1
b   SN:2
i   SA:3
k   SN:4
d   SN:5
f   SN:10
g   SN:11
h   SN:15
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for you case the `man sort`

> If  neither  -t nor -b is in effect, characters in a field are counted
>   **from the beginning of the preceding whitespace**.

So

```
sort -k2.7n file
```

will do job

*HINT!*

If you'd like to count from the line begining you can use `-t` to accept absent char to treat the line as one field:

```
sort -t% -k1.8n file
```